# PHPAGI keeps the channel live

Tags: asterisk

I have a PHP script on extension h. I think extension h should be executed after call is finished, however when one of the parties hangup and AGI script is being executed - another party still can see the call as "active" until the script is finished processing.

In this scenario I need the script to perform some actions for 5 seconds, however for one of the parties call duration increases by 5 "fake" seconds:

```
[10:54:48]  x.php: >>> [NOTICE] One of the parties hanged up <<<
[10:54:53]  x.php: >>> [NOTICE] Script took 5 seconds <<<
[10:54:53]     -- <SIP/from-sip-00000584>AGI Script x.php completed, returning 0
[10:54:53]   == Spawn extension (from-sip, 123456789, 10) exited non-zero on 'SIP/from-sip-00000584'
```

Question: how to hangup both parties before running an AGI script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is expected behavour.

h extension is designed for logging, not for something that can take seconds. Also it can hangup script if it take too much(zombie prevention).

If you need do long-time actions after call is ended, correct way will be put in agi(better fastagi) script just code to log/prepair needed action(put info in temporary sql table or file).

After that you can  do actions based on saved info in external daemon/script. As result every action can take hours without affection asterisk perfomance or calls